# c++ .hpp and .cpp

Tags: c++, linux

Can someone tell me what is the correct way to create a .hpp and .cpp that includes classes, subclasses and methods? Do I have to use `export "C" firstClass* create_object { return new firstClass; }`? (I am working in C++.) Should I have `file.hpp` or `file.h`?

```
#include <string>

//public ?? how can i have this?
class firstClass
{
public:
    firstClass();

    class secondClass
    {
    public:
        secondClass();
        std::string name;
        virtual std::string method1();
    } *sec;

    virtual void DoSomething();
} *first;

// And for a private class?

class private *priv;
```

in file.cpp

```
#include file.hpp
firstClass::firstClass()
{
    sec = new firstClass::secondClass();
}

std::string firstClass::secondClass::method1()
{
    //code
}
```

And now if I have to `extern` an object for each class/subclass? It is necessary if I want to create an .so file and use dlsym and dlopen to access classes, subclasses and methods, modify values, send a reference to a specific method? Thanks!

```
extern "C" firstClass* create_object()
{return new firstClass}
extern "C" secondClass* create_object()
{return new secondClass}
```

Comment: Is C++ your first programming language... It seems you are confusing the syntax with some other language. Take a look at: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: Please, read [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), you're missing the full basics

Comment: I am not a beginner and i do need some help:). I am new to stuff like .h files and how to export classes.

Comment: header files are beginner stuff.

Answer (score 7):

Whether you have `file.hpp` or `file.h` is just a matter of preference. Personally, I use `.hpp` to indicate C++ rather than C.

In C++, unlike for example Java, classes in the global namespace are not `public` or `private`. You can, however, hide or limit access to classes in various ways. For example:

- Having them `private` in another class.
- Using namespaces.

A few other points:

- The syntax for including `file.hpp` is `#include "file.hpp"`
- Your `firstClass` and `secondClass` classes have virtual methods and a default destructor. You should make your destructor `public` and `virtual`, or `protected` and non-`virtual`
- Classes are usually defined like this:

Class definition:

```
class SomeClass {
    // code
};
```

and when you want a pointer to it, you write `SomeClass* myPointer;`, rather than the way you declare `first` and `sec`.

You usually want to put class declarations and/or definitions in header files, along with function declarations. Implementations goes in the source files. Example:

```
// Header file:
class FirstClass {
public:
    FirstClass();
    void DoSomething();
};

// Source file:
FirstClass::FirstClass()
{
    // code
}

void FirstClass::DoSomething()
{
    // code
}
```

I'd recommend you to pick up a C++ textbook, where such basics are plentifully covered. My personal recommendation is [Accelerated C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170353X).